# What is the meaning of the word "distinction" in this context?

Tags: grammar, word-meaning

This is a definition for "ace" from thefreedictionary.com:

> b. To perform **with distinction** on: aced the interview.

I didn't know what **with distinction** means so I checked in the same dictionary. This is the result that I think fits here:

> a. Excellence or eminence, as of performance, character, or reputation: a diplomat **of** distinction.

The problem is that in this sense the word is only used with the preceding preposition **"of"**.

The same preposition is used for the same meaning in macmillandictionary:

> FORMAL the excellent qualities, skills, or features that someone or something has
> **of** (great) distinction: We are fortunate that so many people **of** distinction and talent are present.

On the other hand, in thefreedictionary there is a different meaning of "distinction" which is used with the preposition "with":

> c. Recognition of achievement or superiority; honor: graduated **with** distinction.

The same example can be found in macmillandictionary:

> COUNTABLE/UNCOUNTABLE ​EDUCATION ​BRITISH a very high mark in an examination
> get/gain a distinction: She got a distinction in her piano exam.
> Kevin graduated **with** distinction in history and law.

So which meaning applies to the definition of "ace"? Can you use both with both prepositions?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that "ace" in the phrase "aced the interview" means to perform with excellence, to succeed with no errors.

I suspect this derived from a sports metaphor, as one "aces a shot" in tennis when the opponent is unable to touch the serve at all. But I am not sure, it may be that the sports use is a later derivation.

A "diplomat of distinction" is an excellent diplomat, a diplomat of first quality. To have "graduated with distinction" is to have graduated with an excellent record, to have been a student of top quality.

However the word 'distinction": also suggests soemoen assessing or rating things, adn assignign high marks or giving a prize to the top performers. So a "diplomat of distinction" is not only of high quality as a diplomat, but is seen to be of high quality, has earned a good reputation as a diplomat. One who has "graduated with distinction"  not only has a good record, but is noticed for having done so, is at or ner the top of the student's class.

I believe that this derives from the idea that the best are **distinguished** from the rest.

Note that is a somewhat different sense, an older male who is attractive, but serious is often said to be "distinguished" or "distinguished-looking". A famous or well respected person is said to be a "distinguished scientist" or "distinguished lawyer" or "distinguished statesman" or other profession.